# Reading from raw_data.txt and writing to a results.txt file with processing in Python

Tags: python

This is my first post. I have a function that asks for the number of students. Then, for each student, first three lines contain the following information: Student ID, name, and number of courses taken that semester. Now, for each course, the course number, credit hour, and the percentage of scores earned by the student is listed.

```
def rawdata():
    semester = 1
    if semester == 1:
        raw_file = open('raw_data.txt', 'a')
        total = 0.0
        total2 = 0.0
        num_students = int(input('Enter number of students: '))        
        for student in range(num_students):
            raw_file.write('Start' + '\n')
            student_id = input('Enter student ID: ')
            name = input('Enter Name: ')
            num_classes = int(input('Enter number of courses taken: '))
            raw_file.write(student_id + '\n')
            raw_file.write(name + '\n')
            raw_file.write(str(num_classes) + '\n')
            for classes in range(num_classes):
                course_number = input('Enter Course Number: ')
                credits = int(input('Enter Credit Hours: '))
                GPA1 = float(input('Enter percentage grade for class: '))
                raw_file.write(course_number + '\n')
                raw_file.write(str(credits) + '\n')
                raw_file.write(str(GPA1) + '\n')
                total += credits
            raw_file.write('End' + '\n')
        raw_file.close()
        print('Data has been written')
```

All the data is listed to a txt file and now I need to PULL this information from my raw_data.txt which looks like(varies with inputs):

```
Start
eh2727
Josh D
2
MAT3000
4
95.0
COM3000
4
90.0
End
Start
ah2718
Mary J
1
ENG3010
4
100.0
End
```

and process it so that I can calculate each students GPA. I have each students block of info contained by a Start/End and I don't know how to read this info in my processing function in order for me to calculate their GPA. This is what I have so far:

```
def process():
    data = open('raw_data.txt', 'r')
    results = open('process_results.txt', 'w')
    buffer = []
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('Start'):
            buffer = []
        buffer.append(line)
        if line.startswith("End"):
            for outline in buffer:
                results.write(outline)
```

This simply writes it all into my results text and I don't know how to individually process each block of information to calculate the GPA. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At first I had them separated by '----' but it seemed easier to have them separated in blocks by two conditions.

Comment: Whoops sorry didn't mean to do that! Thanks for editing it:)

Comment: You REALLY should be using CSV or JSON to store the data, with one record per line. And for the love of all that's holy, don't use `input()`! Use `raw_input`.

Comment: No this is just a portion of a larger outside project I've been working on. Please excuse my noob errors this is my second month into programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is your own code writing out the data to the .txt file, you might consider writing it in an easier and/or more fault tolerant format for machine reading, for example JSON or XML. Alternatively, you might want to consider using pickle or cpickle to serialize the data and read it in again.

Anyway, on to your question: how to read the file. Unfortunately, you do not tell us what you want to do with the parsed data. I assume here you want to print it. Normally you would of course create a nice class or classes describing students and courses.

For parsing of files like yours, I use the string method split() a lot. split() is your best friend. See [the python docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html) for more info on string methods.

```
f = open('raw_data.txt', 'rt')
data = f.read()

students = data.split('Start\n')[1:]

for s in students:
    lines = s.split('\n')
    id = lines[0]
    name = lines[1]

    nrcourses = int(lines[2])

    line = 2
    courses = []
    for n in range(nrcourses):
        number = lines[line+1]
        credit = lines[line+2]
        score = lines[line+3]
        courses.append((number, credit, score))
        line += 3

    print 'id: %s; name %s; course list %s' % (id, name, courses)

f.close()
```

Comment: With the parsed data, I need to calculate each students GPA by taking their credits/percentage grade. I have the code that converts the percentage into a grade point. This has been the first time I've heard of JSON or XML. This was very useful thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop a state machine for processing a student record.  You're on the right track with your 'if line.strip() == 'Start', that's a sentinel indicating the beginning of a record.  What you can do at this point is set a flag, processStudentRecord = true, so the next pass through in 'for line in data' you know the line you get is a part of a record.  After setting the flag you should break that if loop so you don't have to have a bunch of elifs.

```
processStudentRecord = False
for line in data:
  if line.strip() == 'Start':
    processStudentRecord = True
    expecting            = "student_id"
    # break here so you go immediately to the next line
  if line.strip() == 'End':
    processStudentRecord = False
    # break here so you go immediately to the next line
  if processStudentRecord:
    # keep track of where you are in the student record
    if expecting == "student_id":
      # extract the student name and then proceed to the next expected line
      expecting = "student_name"
    elif expecting == ""
```

And so on and so forth.  Note, this is a "procedural" method of doing this - one can invent object-oriented or functional solutions.

Comment: To the comment above, yes, if you are generating records, don't generate them in a manner that requires a state machine - save it as JSON, XML, CSV, or something with a format.

Comment: So once I pull for example the credits and percentage grade, how do I use them to calculate the GPA  PER student. I'm not seeing how this generates a record between per start/end block.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a bit of code, but if you trace it through until you understand how it works you'll learn a lot.

First we need to take a class mark and convert it to points. You could write this as a cascade of 13 `if`'s, but I like the data-driven approach:

```
import bisect

def grade_points(pct):
    grade  = [  0,  50,  53,  57,  60,  63,  67,  70,  73,  77,  80,  85,  90]
    points = [0.0, 0.7, 1.0, 1.3, 1.7, 2.0, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.7, 4.0, 4.0]
    if 0 <= pct <= 100:
        # find the highest grade <= pct
        idx = bisect.bisect_right(grade, pct) - 1
        # return the corresponding grade-point
        return points[idx]
    else:
        raise ValueError('pct value should be in 0..100, not {}'.format(pct))
```

Next we want a Student class to make it easy to track per-student data

```
class Student(object):
    str_format = '{id:>8}  {name}  {gpa}'

    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args)==1:    # copy constructor
            student = args[0]
            self.id, self.name, self.classes = student.id, student.name, student.classes
        elif len(args)==3:  # "id", "name", [classes,]
            self.id, self.name, self.classes = args
        else:
            raise ValueError('Failed call to {}.__init__{}'.format(type(self), args))

    @property
    def gpa(self):
        points = sum(hour*grade_points(grade) for code,hour,grade in self.classes)
        hours  = sum(hour                     for code,hour,grade in self.classes)
        return points / hours

    def __str__(self):
        return type(self).str_format.format(id=self.id, name=self.name, classes=self.classes, gpa=self.gpa)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}('{}', '{}', {})".format(type(self).__name__, self.id, self.name, self.classes)
```

So you can create a student and find her GPA like so:

```
sally = Student('ab2773', 'S Atkins', [
    ('MAT3000', 4, 81.0),
    ('ENG3010', 4, 85.0)
])
print sally     # '  ab2773  S Atkins  3.85'
```

Now we need to be able to stream Students to and from a file. This is a bit painful from an OOP point of view, because a Student object really shouldn't need to know anything about a File object or vice-versa, and more so because we want to upgrade you to a better file format - a Student object definitely doesn't need to know about multiple incompatible File types.

I've approached this by subclassing Student; I wrote the `Student.__init__` method in such a way that I can cast back and forth and don't have to rewrite it for the subclasses, so the subclass just knows how to convert itself to and from your nasty file format

```
class NastyFileStudent(Student):
    @classmethod
    def from_strings(cls, strings):
        if len(strings) > 3 and len(strings) == 3 + int(strings[2])*3:
            codes  = strings[3::3]
            hours  = map(int,   strings[4::3])
            grades = map(float, strings[5::3])
            return Student(strings[0], strings[1], zip(codes, hours, grades))
        else:
            # not enough data returned - probably end of file
            return None

    def __str__(self):
        data = [self.id, self.name, str(len(self.classes))] + [str(i) for c in self.classes for i in c]
        return '\n'.join(data)
```

and the file just knows it has Student data but nothing about the contents

```
class NastyFile(object):
    START = 'Start'
    END   = 'End'

    @staticmethod
    def _read_until(endfn, seq):
        is_end = endfn if callable(endfn) else lambda s: s==endfn
        data = []
        for s in seq:
            if is_end(s):
                break
            else:
                data.append(s)
        return data

    def __init__(self, name, mode='r'):
        self.name = name
        self.mode = mode
        self._f = open(name, mode)
        self.lines = (ln.strip() for ln in self._f)

    def __del__(self):
        self._f.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        _       = NastyFile._read_until(NastyFile.START, self.lines)
        strings = NastyFile._read_until(NastyFile.END,   self.lines)

        student = NastyFileStudent.from_strings(strings)
        if student is None:
            raise StopIteration()
        else:
            return student

    def read(self):
        return list(self)

    def write(self, s):
        if not hasattr(s, '__iter__'):
            s = [s]
        for student in s:
            self._f.write('{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(NastyFile.START, str(NastyFileStudent(student)), NastyFile.END))
```

Now we can read and write files of student records like so

```
>>> students = NastyFile('student_records.txt').read()

>>> for s in students:
...     print s
  eh2727  Josh D  4.0
  ah2718  Mary J  4.0

>>> students.append(sally)

>>> students.sort(key=lambda s: s.name.rsplit(None,1)[-1])  # sort by last name

>>> for s in students:
...     print s
  ab2773  S Atkins  3.85
  eh2727  Josh D  4.0
  ah2718  Mary J  4.0

>>> newfile = NastyFile('new_records.txt', 'w')
>>> newfile.write(students)

>>> for i,s in enumerate(NastyFile('new_records.txt'), 1):
...     print '{:>2}: {}'.format(i, s)
 1:   ab2773  S Atkins  3.85
 2:   eh2727  Josh D  4.0
 3:   ah2718  Mary J  4.0
```